# Change execution order of Laravel Migrations

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration, laravel-artisan

I'm having some of the issues detailed in ["General error: 1005 Can't create table" Using Laravel Schema Build and Foreign Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894250/general-error-1005-cant-create-table-using-laravel-schema-build-and-foreign/18914911#18914911)

I understand why the errors are happening - my current migration order isn't creating my parent tables before the child ones, and so my foreign keys are getting all messed up because the tables they depend on don't exist yet. But it seems a bit hacked (and inconvenient) to change the migration order by arbitrarily changing the timestamps of each migration to make them execute in the proper order.

```
2015_06_29_191903_create_child_table
2015_07_06_144544_create_parent_table
```

Is there a good Artisan tool to change the order in which migrations are applied? I haven't found anything online but people just making up fake timestamps in the order they want.

Comment: you can change the batch number in migration table,or may create another migration for creating foreign key

Answer (score 4):

You can manually change date of the migration and so the order of migrations but IS NOT RECOMMENDED. That will mess up your the migration table and will get errors on migrate:rollback and so.
If its not too much pain, and there is not much data in DB, drop it, reorder migrations modifying dates and migrate all, fresh.