# Laravel 5.1 foreign key migration error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-5.1

I get this weird error when executing my constraints migration
When I execute this migration I get

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'flowtime_dev.#sql-85bb_52' (errno: 121) (SQL: alter table `questions` add constraint questions_inventory_i
  d_foreign foreign key (`inventory_id`) references `inventories` (`id`) on delete cascade)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'flowtime_dev.#sql-85bb_52' (errno: 121)
```

I've read that the data types in different tables should match ( like int(10) to int(10)) and they do, this is also the last migration that I have ( all the tables exist and have been created by other migrations before).

I seriously have no idea what to do anymore :(. Could someone help?
I have seen similar posts, but they have not fixed the problem so far for me.

The migration is as follows:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('questions', function ($table) {
            $table->integer('inventory_id')->unsigned()->change();
            $table->foreign('inventory_id')
                ->references('id')->on('inventories')
                ->onDelete('cascade');  
        });

        Schema::table('question_response', function ($table) {
            $table->integer('question_id')->unsigned()->change();
            $table->foreign('question_id')
                ->references('id')->on('questions')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

        Schema::table('question_response', function ($table) {
            $table->integer('sample_result_set_id')->unsigned()->change();             
            $table->foreign('sample_result_set_id')
                ->references('id')->on('sample_response_set')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

        Schema::table('inventory_response', function ($table) {
            $table->integer('inventory_id')->unsigned()->change();  
            $table->foreign('inventory_id')
                ->references('id')->on('inventories')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

        Schema::table('inventory_response', function ($table) {
            $table->integer('sample_result_set_id')->unsigned()->change(); 
            $table->foreign('sample_result_set_id')
                ->references('id')->on('sample_response_set')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    }
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @AaronFranco MySql

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of your migration turn off foreign key constraints.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Then, when the data is migrated, turn them back on.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

If that doesn't work, then try adding the following line.

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB'
```

[Further, you can rename the constraint since the name may already be used...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894250/general-error-1005-cant-create-table-using-laravel-schema-build-and-foreign)

```
$table->foreign('inventory_id', 'fk_questions_inventory_id')->...
```

Comment: added DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0'); before and DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1'); after the migration ends @AaronFranco

Comment: innoDB did not help aswll @AaronFranco

Answer (score 1):

Try to use two separate migrations.

Create first migration, which will create tables and all columns (put everything except `$table->foreign` clauses here). Run `migrate` command. Do not execute second one, temporarily remove it from migrations directory, if you've already have this migration.

Then create second migration, which will add foreign keys to **already created** columns (use only `$table->foreign` clauses here). Run `migrate` command again.

This helped me, when I was in the same situation. I hope it will work for you too.

Comment: the main problem is that I am stupid, some of the migration had run through already, which meant that it failed every time, it took me some time to realize that. Thank you for the help :)