# Laravel migrations don't seem to be working on certain computers

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

everyone. This is my first post in my 2 year software development career, and I'm posting it because of no relevant answer and I have run out of ideas of why this issue occurs.

So I'm running a small project where we are developing our own website on Laravel 5.6.28 PHP framework on PHP 7.2.4 and MySQL 5.7.21.

Everything seems to be fine most of the time and I have been working with the Laravel framework for about a year now and I had this issue a while ago, but that was on a test project, so I didn't really bother to try fixing it, but now it occured again.

It happens when I'm sharing my project code with other users from my project - it works on most computers, except for one. And the error message is
     **Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table ... Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed.**

All the solutions I found were to check if the corresponding column has the unsigned() added to it, but I did check it and all the foreign key fields have it. Also the foreign keys are added after creating the tables.

It seems to be crashing on every table, but it works on all the other project members computers.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Here's the code for creating user table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nick_name', 50)->unique();
        $table->string('first_name', 50);
        $table->string('last_name', 50);
        $table->string('email', 100)->unique();
        $table->string('password', 255);
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('twitter', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('facebook', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('instagram', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('linkedin', 50)->nullable();
        $table->float('commitment')->default(1);
        $table->string('position', 100)->default('Employee')->nullable();
        $table->datetime('last_login')->nullable();
        $table->integer('active')->unsigned()->default(1);
        $table->integer('image_id')->unsigned()->default(1);
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->rememberToken();
    });

    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('image_id')->references('id')->on('files');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
    });
}
```

Comment: did you try do delete the existing table?, then run php artisan migrate:refresh

Comment: what are the specs of the environment of this random computer that this isn't working on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["General error: 1005 Can't create table" Using Laravel Schema Build and Foreign Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894250/general-error-1005-cant-create-table-using-laravel-schema-build-and-foreign)

Comment: @MathewMagante There were no tables, except the migrations table, created in the first place, so there was nothing to delete. Setting the default engine to InnoDB also didn't seem to fix the issue. What I have figured out is that it tries to put a constraint on a table that doesn't yet exist, but I don't understand why. Isn't Laravel supposed to handle that by using the Schema::table statement? And why does it work for everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you, i would update my code like below and check if that works or not,

```
public function up()
{
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('nick_name', 50)->unique();
    $table->string('first_name', 50);
    $table->string('last_name', 50);
    $table->string('email', 100)->unique();
    $table->string('password', 255);
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    $table->string('twitter', 50)->nullable();
    $table->string('facebook', 50)->nullable();
    $table->string('instagram', 50)->nullable();
    $table->string('linkedin', 50)->nullable();
    $table->float('commitment')->default(1);
    $table->string('position', 100)->default('Employee')->nullable();
    $table->datetime('last_login')->nullable();
    $table->integer('active')->unsigned()->default(1);
    $table->integer('image_id')->unsigned()->default(1);
    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->default(1);
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->foreign('image_id')->references('id')->on('files');
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
});


}
```

But it is strange that it works in other computer but not in one.

Good Luck!