# General error: 1005 Can't create table `mysql`.`user`

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying migrate a table to sql. I tried looking for all answers that i found here but none of them worked.  I am new to PHP and laravel and it is driving me crazy. Php and sql version are from latest xampp. Here is the error I am getting.

[image: The error I am getting]

I already dropped the existing 'user' table. updated composer and run migrate:rollback but still wont work

Here is the code i am running currently.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUserTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');        
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('user');
}
}
```

Comment: "General error: 1005 Can't create table `mysql`.`user`" Really? I don't know what you are doing? ..

Comment: I dont know what im doing either

Comment: "I already dropped the existing 'user' table." Dropping `mysql.user` and recreating is not very smart.. Most likely you can reinstall the complete MySQL server now..

Comment: Can you please add your XAMPP configurations? I think that Laravel can't connect to XAMPP mysql server

Comment: Notice mysql.user in the title and error in the screenshot @LukStorms it looks like the topicstarter is trying to create a user table in the mysql database.

Comment: Did you select a DB when you created your connection? Sounds like you are at the root of the system but you should be in a database

Comment: Did you tried this @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894250/general-error-1005-cant-create-table-using-laravel-schema-build-and-foreign ? in create add `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';` your db engine!

Comment: ```mysql.user``` is mysql internal user storage. Never ever drop or mess up this table. [ref](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqluser-table/). Create your own namespace like ```lisandro.user```.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Never mind, the picture was too small for me to see clearly. But after looking at it in normal resolution I noticed that it backticks it anyway.

Comment: yes i was too dumb to mess with the mysql.user, i dropped it.. i should have researched carefully before doing any further actions.

Comment: Your problem is that in your `.env` file you put `DB_DATABASE=mysql` for some reason. This mistake wouldn't have been a problem if you hadn't used your root DB credentials for application access. You'll need to reinstall MySQL and ensure your application is configured properly next time.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem before. Try edit in `config/database.php` like this:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8', // Edit in here: 'utf8mb4' => utf8'
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', // And here
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```