# How do I solve General error: 1005 Can't create table?

Tags: database, laravel, migrate

I want to migrate my migration that have **foreign key** in `users` table referenced on `roles` table but I always get

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `db_pkl_smk`.`#sql-435c_67` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id`) references `roles` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)",

Is there something wrong with my migration?

I have changed the default timestamp file from Laravel to avoid errors when adding foreign keys, the file name looks like below :

```
2019_04_02_133714_create_roles_table.php
2019_04_03_030518_create_users_table.php
```

2019_04_02_133714_create_roles_table.php

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('desc');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

2019_04_03_030518_create_users_table.php

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles') 
               ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["General error: 1005 Can't create table" Using Laravel Schema Build and Foreign Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894250/general-error-1005-cant-create-table-using-laravel-schema-build-and-foreign)

Comment: One possible reason is, role.id is bigIncrements so it will be integer(20) unsigned, while in users.role_id it's integer(10) unsigned. Let you declare `$table->bigInteger('role_id');`