# Why I can't do a migration with constraint foreign key

Tags: laravel, database-migration, laravel-7

for a homework i have to do a todolist in laravel 7 i do my db but when i try to create a foreign key to the table task

[image] and a table categories 
[image]
the program fail with the formula :"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1824 Failed to open the referenced table 'categories' (SQL: alter table `tasks` add constraint `tasks_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`categ
ory_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade)"

i've done it a lot of time but i don't understand why i doesn't work if someone could explains
the right way to do it

Comment: Which of the migrations did you create first?

Comment: Just a recommendation, paste the real code using code-blocks instead of embedding images of your code

Comment: As @GusCosta says, put creating of `categories` executes first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The migration is trying to create the `tasks` table before `categories`, the `categories` table still doesn't exist at the time it tries to create the FK.

Swap the order of your migrations changing its filename. Each migration file at `database/migrations` has a date-time before the name. Alter it so the tasks migration has a date greater than the categories one.

Answer (score 0):

will Gus Costa is right and you should do as he says but i want to add that your 
foreign key should be **unsigned**

and here you will find some good answers
["General error: 1005 Can't create table" Using Laravel Schema Build and Foreign Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894250/general-error-1005-cant-create-table-using-laravel-schema-build-and-foreign)

```
    // CREATING TABLE
    Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->integer('field_id')->unsigned; //for field that contains foreign key constraint
    });

    // FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT
    Schema::table('stock', function ($table) {
        $table->foreign('field_id')->references('id')->on('some_table')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```